# Why does the converting a dateutil rrule to a string and back make it lose its timezone information?

Tags: python, python-dateutil

The [dateutil.rrule](http://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/rrule.html) module has an `rrule` class which has a custom `__str__` method to convert its instances to strings, and a `rrulestr` function which does the opposite, namely, convert the string back to an object.

It seems, however, that the `_dtstart` attribute of the `rrule` loses its timezone information when converting to a string and back. For example, in the following script:

```
from dateutil.rrule import rrule, rrulestr, DAILY
from dateutil.parser import parse

start = parse("8 Feb 2017 14:00 UTC")
my_rrule = rrule(DAILY, dtstart=start)

my_rrule2 = rrulestr(str(my_rrule))

assert my_rrule._dtstart == my_rrule2._dtstart
```

the assertion leads to a

```
TypeError: can't compare offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes
```

Specifically, I noticed that `my_rrule.dtstart` has the representation

```
datetime.datetime(2017, 2, 8, 14, 0, tzinfo=tzutc())
```

whereas `my_rrule2._dtstart` is

```
datetime.datetime(2017, 2, 8, 14, 0)
```

Why is the timezone information lost? Is this not a deficiency in the `__str__`/`rrulestr` combination?

Comment: This is probably a bug and can be reported at [dateutil's issue tracker on github](https://github.com/dateutil/dateutil/issues). Generally it's not a good idea to use time zones with rrule because of some ambiguities that come up around DST, but for UTC and other fixed-offset zones, that's not an issue.

Comment: By the way, it might be very difficult to do this correctly unless you happen to be using the relatively unpopular `tzical` time zones, since the RRULE spec has a time zone specification that is not necessarily compatible with compiled zoneinfo files (e.g. Olson zones).

Comment: Thanks, I reported the bug as https://github.com/dateutil/dateutil/issues/348.